# Red spellcheck squiggles remain in chrome after editing is disabled

Tags: html, google-chrome, contenteditable, spell-checking, browser-bugs

**UPDATE:** This has been identified as a bug in Chrome. (Thanks @michael-robinson)

In Chrome (v22 at least), I notice that it's possible for spellchecking "red squiggly" underlines to remain  even after contentEditable has been disabled.

I made a jsfiddle to demonstrate: [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RegVn/1/).

[image: squiggles and spelling errors]

Even if I set the attribute `spellcheck="false"` before disabling `contentEditable`, they remain.

Anyone know how a nice way to solve or work around this? Ideally I'd retain the built-in spell checking functionality when the content is editable.

Comment: What about instead of disabling the contentEditable, you remove the attribute?

Comment: @BrianNoah I'll give it a go, although the contentEditable attribute seems to be respected with a value of `false`

Comment: @BrianNoah Nah, doesn't seem to change the broken behaviour of the spellcheck underlines. Thanks, though.

Comment: Thought I'd try, Have you tried the autocorrect="false" attribute?

Comment: @BrianNoah Hrm ... didn't work either. Thanks for the input

Comment: This is a bug in chrome and has been reported here: [Issue 155781](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=155781&q=spellcheck&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified)

Comment: Awesome, I actually submitted that, but hadn't realised they'd picked it up...

Comment: This bug takes 3 years and still not resolved?

Comment: Wow. It's been that long? Obviously not on the roadmap!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>Have you tried setting `display: none` (using CSS) and then setting the display back to what it was? Might force Chrome to redraw the element...</del> (didn't work, see other solution below)

Alternatively, you could create a copy of the element (but with contenteditable disabled) placing it just after the original element and deleting the original element.

**UPDATE 1**: first solution didn't work, but second one does. Updated JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RegVn/6/

**UPDATE 2**: above solution uses innerHTML which removes destroys event handlers. It also destroys the selection/caret position.

New method uses jQuery's `clone()` method (in deep clone mode) to create a copy of the object (which copies over the event handlers), and has custom functions to save a reference to the selection, and restore it afterwards. Note that the selection save/restore functions wont work in ie6-8, but I thought that this was acceptable as the question is tagged Chrome. Updated JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RegVn/23/

Comment: Creating a new element which is the same as the old one works - I've updated the JSfiddle with an example (see edited answer).

Comment: Hey, thanks heaps for creating a jsfiddle to demonstrate, I appreciate that. Unfortunately this solution has a few significant drawbacks which I outline in my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12888119/26331

Comment: @aaaidan Updated to remove 2 of your drawbacks. I'm afraid this is probably still quite cpu intensive (if not more so), but it does address the other problems.

Comment: Brilliant! This is an excellent workaround. I had no idea that a deep clone preserved events, thanks! I commented the line forcing contentEditable on removing the squiggs, and removed lines when leaving edit mode: 
http://jsfiddle.net/RegVn/26/

Answer (score 3):

Adding the attribute `spellcheck="false"` to the element works for me.

Comment: Haha, jubilation! This must be fixed now. I'll check. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The spellcheck attribute specifies whether the element is to have its spelling and grammar checked or not:

[spellcheck="false"](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_global_spellcheck.asp)

Comment: Ah, thanks - I should probably mention that they persist even if spellcheck="false" is set after they appear.

Answer (score 1):

If you update the innerHTML of the element, the spellcheck will be re-evaluated, so they'll disappear if `spellcheck="false"` or if the element isn't editable.

For example:

```
myElement.innerHTML = myElement.innerHTML + " "; // add a space to force a change.
```

This has significant disadvantages:

- Event handlers and javascript objects referencing any elements will be invalidated (all elements inside the element are effectively removed from the dom). This also means that javascript-only properties, such as a checkbox's `indeterminate` property or any other custom properties, will be destroyed.
- The selection or caret position is destroyed.
- If you have a large amount of content, this is a non-trivial operation for the cpu, especially on mobile.

This is okay for now, but I'm still looking for a better answer. Suggestions?

Comment: See above again. I can't make it less cpu intensive (it is possible that there is another approach which would allow this), but the new method will keep event handlers and restore the selection.

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = $("#editor").html();
$("#editor").html("")
$("#editor").attr('spellcheck', 'false');
$("#editor").html(content);
```

try this code and it should work. This is based on the same previous answer of cloning inner HTML.

Works in  FF and Chrome.

Comment: Great, this is compact and easy to understand. But unfortunately, it will will destroy any event handlers that exist for the content.